# What profilers and analyzers are there for Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang, profiler, lexical-analysis

Are there any good code profilers/analyzers for Erlang? I need something that can build a call graph (eg gprof) for my code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For static code analysis you have [Xref](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/xref.html) and [Dialyzer](http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/hipe/dialyzer/), for profiling you can use cprof, fprof or eprof, reference [here](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.5.5/lib/tools-2.5.5/doc/html/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

The 'fprof' module includes profiling features. From the [fprof module documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/fprof.html):

```
fprof:apply(foo, create_file_slow, [junk, 1024]).
fprof:profile().
fprof:analyse().
```

`fprof:apply` (or `trace`) runs the function, `profile` converts the trace file into something useful, and `analyse` prints out the summary. This will give you a list of function calls observed, what called them, and what they called, as well as wall-clock timing info.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: https://github.com/virtan/eep
You could get something like this https://raw.github.com/virtan/eep/master/doc/sshot1.png