# Is there an equivalent module of python's timeit in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

In python you can time small pieces of execution time of code using the timeit module.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Is there an equivalent in Elixir ?

Comment: I know it's not execution timing but this might also help if you're trying to improve code performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204926/profiler-analyzer-for-erlang

Answer (score 7):

The simplest tool would be to use Erlang's `:timer` module, with one of it's `tc` variants. It returns execution time in microseconds and the result of the function as a tuple. To time an anonymous function you can do

```
{time, res} = :timer.tc fn -> :timer.sleep(1000) end
# {1000575, :ok}

{time, res} = :timer.tc(fn(ms) -> :timer.sleep(ms) end, [1000])
# {1001283, :ok}
```

To time a module function you can do

```
defmodule Sleepy do
  def sleep(ms) do
    :timer.sleep(ms)
  end
end

{time, res} = :timer.tc(&Sleepy.sleep/1, [1000])
# {1001106, :ok}

{time, res} = :timer.tc(Sleepy, :sleep, [1000])
# {1000352, :ok}
```

[Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) is another option, which has a friendlier API for measuring times, amongst other things, however if all you need is to time something, `:timer` is more than sufficient with a bit of wrapper code.